# How to get the PBA for a given LBA in SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, layout

**Device**: SATA SSD and NVMe SSD (CHS conversion not work)
I can get the right LBAs of a file (`postgresql-data/base/13495/5002`) via

```sh
> sudo hdparm --fibmap postgresql-data/base/13495/5002

 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 2048; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0  843338528  843338543         16
```

But I want to know the physical block addresses of these LBAs. In HDD, this is easy with CHS conversion. But SSDs have FTL that stores the LBA-PBA mapping table (L2P table). I have to know this table to know the PBA. How to make this?

#### Why I am asking

From the result shown with `sudo hdparm --fibmap`, it seems that the file is stored serially in the disk (i.e., from LBA 843338528 to 843338543). But does it shows the truth?

So I want to figure out if the file locates in different packages(chips)/dies/planes/blocks of the SSD (like this figure: https://www.memblaze.com/en/images/xin-pic10.jpg), or a file is only stored in one package(chips)/die/plane.

Thanks!